# when I try to Run Nuit 3 Test explorer : Getting Could not load file or assembly 'Tech Talk.Specrun.frame.Utils

Tags: specflow

[25/01/2018 15:39:23 Informational] ------ Load Playlist started ------
[25/01/2018 15:39:23 Informational] ========== Load Playlist finished (0:00:00.015627) ==========
[25/01/2018 15:39:24 Informational] ------ Discover test started ------
[25/01/2018 15:39:25 Informational] NUnit Adapter 3.7.0.0: Test discovery starting
[25/01/2018 15:39:25 Informational] Assembly contains no NUnit 3.0 tests: C:\Users\mohammed.manzoor\source\repos\FlowquoteTest1\FlowMethods\bin\Debug\FlowMethods.dll
[25/01/2018 15:39:25 Informational] Assembly contains no NUnit 3.0 tests: C:\Users\mohammed.manzoor\source\repos\FlowquoteTest1\FlowPages\bin\Debug\FlowPages.dll
[25/01/2018 15:39:26 Informational] Assembly contains no NUnit 3.0 tests: C:\Users\mohammed.manzoor\source\repos\FlowquoteTest1\FlowquoteTest1\bin\Debug\FlowquoteTest1.dll
[25/01/2018 15:39:26 Informational] NUnit Adapter 3.7.0.0: Test discovery complete
[25/01/2018 15:39:26 Informational] SpecFlow + Runner Discovery started
[25/01/2018 15:39:26 Informational] SpecRun: not SpecRun assembly - skip: C:\Users\mohammed.manzoor\source\repos\FlowquoteTest1\FlowMethods\bin\Debug\FlowMethods.dll
[25/01/2018 15:39:26 Informational] SpecRun: not SpecRun assembly - skip: C:\Users\mohammed.manzoor\source\repos\FlowquoteTest1\FlowPages\bin\Debug\FlowPages.dll
[25/01/2018 15:39:26 Informational] SpecRun Evaluation Mode: Please purchase at http://www.specflow.org/plus to remove test execution delay.
[25/01/2018 15:39:26 Informational] Error for test assembly C:\Users\mohammed.manzoor\source\repos\FlowquoteTest1\FlowquoteTest1\bin\Debug\FlowquoteTest1.dll
[25/01/2018 15:39:26 Informational] System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.Utils, Version=1.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.Utils, Version=1.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at TechTalk.SpecRun.VisualStudio.TestAdapter.SpecRunTestDiscoverer.CreateTestSuiteProvider(ITestLogger testLogger)
   at TechTalk.SpecRun.VisualStudio.TestAdapter.SpecRunTestDiscoverer.DiscoverTests(String source, IDiscoveryContext discoveryContext, IMessageLogger logger, ITestCaseDiscoverySink discoverySink)
   at TechTalk.SpecRun.VisualStudio.TestAdapter.SpecRunTestDiscoverer.DiscoverTests(IEnumerable`1 sources, IDiscoveryContext discoveryContext, IMessageLogger logger, ITestCaseDiscoverySink discoverySink)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible an issue with Visual Studio's cache. Every now and then, Visual Studio seems to have trouble with extensions, and clearing the cache tends to fix these issues.

The following information is copied from the Troubleshooting section of the SpecFlow+ FAQ:
I'm trying to run my SpecFlow+ Runner tests in Visual Studio test window, but they fail with an assembly load error
In some cases the cache folder of Visual Studio Test Adapter gets corrupted. You need to clear the cache to resolve this:

Close all Visual Studio instances
Open the folder %TEMP%\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions\
Delete all folders named *SpecRun*

I hope that sorts your issue out. Visual Studio also seems to sometimes add directories without "SpecRun" in the name (e.g. just "2.2.0").

Comment: Above Answer from Specflow Support Team

Answer (score 1):

Looks like something is wrong with your project.

Please open an issue here: http://specflow.org/specflow-support/ so we can have a look at your project.

Comment: Hi Andreas    I Uploaded to my repo   into specflow support  Could you please have a look my project and suggest me how can i find the solution for above issue

Comment: We got it. As it's Friday evening here in Vienna, I will have a look at next week.